# OSX Apache Web Server El Capitan Upgrade 404 Error

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf, osx-elcapitan

I was receiving a 404 error after upgrading to El Capitan when trying to access pages in my local sites directory after they were already enabled at the user level when running OSX Yosemite. The issue was that Apache reset the httpd.conf file to its default which disables the user folders to load files from. So http://localhost loaded fine BUT http://localhost/~username/index.html would NOT load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fix:

back up the "new" config file that was created:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf_capitan
```

restore the "old" config file that was renamed:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: @Devrim did you confirm the contents of your /etc/apache2 folder?

Comment: My issue was the php module commented on the config file. It's all good now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198875/404-not-found-after-el-capitan-update/33199981#33199981

Comment: Using the httpd.conf~previous didn't work for me.  However, there was also a httpd.conf.pre-update in the /etc/apache2 directory as well.

I copied that one over to httpd.conf and it worked.

Don't forget to restart apache!  (sudo apachectl restart)