# 404 Not Found after El Capitan update

Tags: macos, localhost, http-status-code-404, lamp, osx-elcapitan

Localhost is misconfigured after El-Capitan update yesterday. Im really not a mac person so I don't know how to fix this. Localhost is working fine but my username/sites can't be found.

Exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003131/osx-apache-web-server-el-capitan-upgrade-404-error) but the answer provided does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Edit the apache configuration. In my case, the php module was commented so:

Run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` via terminal and uncomment the following if they are commented:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get "permission denied", check if you have comment out these lines.

```
220 <Directory />
221     AllowOverride none
222     Require all denied
223 </Directory>
```